# Unload AJAX event get's noticed by firefox on subsequent request (causing the connection to this website is not fully secure)

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, http, firefox

In firefox I see an HTTP AJAX request I fire on the "unload" event (used for statistic purposes) getting noticed on the subsequent (HTTPS) request, this causes the browser saying that not all the content on the page is secure.

My (simplified) code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function doGet(){
                $.get(
                    "ajax.php?_" + Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999)
                );
            }

            $(window).on("unload", function (e) {
                doGet();
            });
        </script>
        <a href="https://test.local/test2.php">Test</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this so my visitors see that the request is fully secure?
This issue is only visible on firefox, I have no problems on chrome.

*Print screen Firebug window:*
[image: Print screen Firebug window]

Comment: What if you write out the jQuery.get() to jQuery.ajax() and specify the https:// connection in the 'url' parameter?

Comment: Unfortunately that's no option since this particular resource isn't available through HTTPS (changing .get() to .ajax() doesn't solve it either since .get() is a shorthand function)